# Capture MIDI notes while on playback?

Tags: java, midi, playback

I am trying to build a program to display MIDI notes on screen while it is played by the Synthesizer, using Java Sound API (javax.sound.midi). The MIDI file needs to be loaded from disk, and I am having some trouble on connecting the Sequencer to the Synthesizer, so that I can capture the notes when the Synthesizer plays it.

I can't just load the sequence to the Sequencer and use sequencer.start() because then I would not be able to capture the midi messages and thus would lose the note_on messages. On the other hand, if I connect the sequencer to the synthesizer and just send the messages to the synth it will just play all the notes with the wrong timing. Is there a way of sending the messages to the synthesizer JUST when it is meant to be played? There must be something with midi ticks that will do it, but I can't figure it out. Also, I couldn't understand very well how does Java manages midi ticks.

Answer (score 0):

If the Sequencer supports multiple Transmitters, connect two of them to the Synthesizer and to your own Receiver.